# How to index the first column which has no header?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following data frame for example. What I am trying to do is get the first column to be the index. When  I try to do this, it doesn't work. When I am able to set the index successfully, I get a bunch of NaN's. Thank you!

```
    0   1       2
0   842 Bill    Smith
1   841 John    Fisher
2   843 Barb    Macdonald
```

Comment: Could you share your attempt, even if it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). Assuming your dataframe is variable `df`:

```
df = df.set_index(0)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much.